# Android layout match root parent

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen

How can I make layout "almost fullscreen" ? I mean I dont want there that Icon and app name ("Tests"). I just want to show the top area with battery and signal status and be able to draw whatever I want to rest of the screen

Image is from Eclipse "Graphical layout" 3.2in HVGA slider (ADP1) - portrait

[image: Layout]

I tried to make my layout to fill parent and delete everything else but that icon and text is still there

**Layout xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#131325" 
     >    
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="myTests.homeSpace"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
     <application
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <activity
             android:name=".TestsActivity"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>

         <activity
             android:name=".screen1" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
     </application>
 </manifest>
```

Thank you

Comment: For that you've to modify the theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing the image and Title you've to use the `Theme` Try below code into your `AndroidManifest.xml`-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="myTests.homeSpace"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
     <application
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <activity
             android:name=".TestsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>

         <activity
             android:name=".screen1" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
     </application>
 </manifest>
```

Have a look at [Theme_NoTitleBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_NoTitleBar) You can do this by programmatically also with below code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

You've to use the `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before calling the `setContentView(R.layout.main);` only. If you want to use this for all your activities, then you've to give this each activites before `setContentView(R.layout.main);` method.

Comment: wow it works on emulator, but inside eclipse when designing the layout, I still can see there that icon and text, can I get rid of it?

Comment: Yes. Just open your xml layout. Right most corner, there you can see the drop down list. From there you can see the Theme files. [See this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RcNCW.png)

Answer (score 0):

or in java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//<-----------
```